# How to count number of packets received from a specific host?

Tags: linux, iptables, tcpdump

I want to inspect which host is sending the most traffic to my server. How can I get something like this:

```
172 192.168.1.1
19  192.168.1.56
```

Which means that in a specific time interval, my serve received 172 packets from `192.168.1.1` and 19 packets from `192.168.1.56`.

How can I do this?

Comment: What type of packets you want to count? IP or TCP or UDP?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im  I want to count tcp packets

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use tcpdump for that:

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ 1 ]
do
  timeout -t 5 tcpdump -n -i eth0 "tcp port 22" 2> /dev/null > /tmp/capture.txt
  echo
  date
  cat /tmp/capture.txt | grep -oE "((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.]){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)" | sort | uniq -c
done
```

It will produce periodic statistics by counting IPv4 addresses from the output of `tcpdump`.

With `pcap` filter, you can easily limit what traffic is wanted.
In the example script `"tcp port 22"` limits traffic to SSH.

Example output:

```
Fri Jun 28 16:05:10 UTC 2019
     53 10.0.0.2
     53 10.0.0.99

Fri Jun 28 16:05:16 UTC 2019
     37 10.0.0.2
     37 10.0.0.99

Fri Jun 28 16:05:21 UTC 2019

Fri Jun 28 16:05:26 UTC 2019
      5 10.0.0.2
      5 10.0.0.99
```

Because tcpdump is not running all the time, the counting may lose some packets sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you you can use this:
http://www.catonmat.net/blog/traffic-accounting-with-iptables/

You just have to edit the awk script a little bit to print the number of packets rather than number of bytes [and print IP address second rather than first if that is critical].